# Illegal Instruction 4 (Made a mess of python installation, no idea what I'm doing)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos

I am inexperienced with bash, python, and simply a lot of the basics/fundamentals some might take knowledge of for granted. I am using macOS 10.7.5. After installing numpy but getting error messages when importing in IDLE, I decided to reinstall python 3.7, but am getting several error messages now.

Some time ago, I installed python 3.7 from the python website, and it worked just fine. However, I had a great deal of trouble installing packages. The final straw was when I "successfully" installed numpy, but then I got a string of error messages when trying to import it in IDLE. I decided to try to re-install python, so I deleted python 3.7 and re-installed the same version from the same place.

However, when I tried typing "python3" in the Terminal, I got: "Segmentation Fault: 11". I researched it and understood that it had to do something with memory, so I must have uninstalled/installed wrong. However, I tried typing "python3" again, and got "Illegal Instruction: 4". After several tries, this is the only message I get anymore, and the segmentation fault does not appear.

I have no idea what I'm doing, and I don't know where to start. All I really know is that I've made a mess of the situation. I realize the solution might appear obvious, but I am completely inexperienced and in the dark right now. Thank you for reading this, I hope I can learn from you.

(Please ask for any and all information you might need, as I also don't know what exactly you might want to know.)

EDIT:

I realized when I re-installed Python, I had installed the macOS 10.9+ version. I uninstalled it and installed the correct version (10.6+). IDLE works and so does pip, but now I am getting the original error when I try to import numpy.

This is what I get:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    from . import fft
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .fftpack import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack.py", line 44, in <module>
    from . import fftpack_lite as fftpack
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-37m-darwin.so```
````

Comment: Which python package manager do you use? pip/conda? To be honest, I don't think this will be easily fixable from people on stackoverflow, try to reach out to someone you have physical access to, he/she should come over and take a look at it. Something is messed up.

Comment: I use pip. Also, I edited my question, I made a little bit of progress (I think...)

Comment: How did you install *numpy*? You need a version built against the same OS version you're actually running. Personally, I use [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/), and it does a pretty good job of doing all that right. If you installed Nix, running `nix-shell -p 'python37.withPackages (ps: [ps.numpy])'` would start a shell with Python 3.7 with numpy in its path (backed by files in a read-only location, and thus resistant to attempts to tamper / mess it up).

Comment: Can I use Nix with Mac? I also saw "homebrew" referenced a lot, but it appears they no longer support my version of macOS (10.7.5). I have numpy 1.16.3 according to the Terminal.